# C# - ウインドウを閉じてもマルチスレッドの動作が終了しない。

Tags: c#, wpf

ウインドウを閉じてもマルチスレッドの動作が終了しないという事態に悩んでいます。
現在のソースは、
Aクラス・Bクラス・Cクラスがあり、AクラスからマルチスレッドでB・Cクラスを呼び出し実行しています。
（Aクラス・Bクラス・CクラスはCSファイルで分けています。）
ウインドウは一つだけしか表示しておらず、そのウインドウの閉じるボタンを押下すると、
アプリケーションが終了すると考えていました。
しかし、B・Cクラスの処理はウインドウを閉じた後も動作し続けています。

ウインドウの閉じるボタンを押下したと同時に全ての処理を終了したいのですが、
windowのclosingイベント内でB・Cクラスの処理を終了させる方法しかないのでしょうか？
他に良い案があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ThreadオブジェクトのIsBackgroundプロパティがfalseになっている可能性があります。
ワーカーとして使う場合はStartメソッドを呼び出す前にtrueをセットしておく必要があります。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
ThreadオブジェクトのIsBackgroundプロパティがfalseになっていました。
trueに設定することで、問題を解決することが出来ました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: @S.N 一般的な留意事項をお伝えしておくと、B・Cクラスの処理が処理途中で強制終了されても安全かを確認しておいた方が良いです。例）ファイル出力処理が含まれていると、半分だけ書きこんだタイミングで強制終了→次回アプリ起動時に中途半端なファイルを読み込めない。

Comment: 正しくスレッドを終了する為に、本来ならスレッド側に終了を伝えてメイン側で Join してから終了した方が良いと思います。ゴミを残さないのであれば構いませんが。

Comment: 細かな補足をありがとうございます。
その方向で実装していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ウィンドウの開き方に依存します。WPFアプリケーションプロジェクトであれば既定でウィンドウの終了時にアプリケーションも終了します。
App.xamlの[Application.ShutdownModeプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx)で制御できます。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
表示中のウインドウは既定に設定されていました。
Application.ShutdownModeを設定しましたが、問題は解決しませんでしした。